# Check if a dialog/widget/window still open to prevent the duplication

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, duplication

How to prevent open a window many times.

**See the following image:**

[image]

What I want is if the window still open does not open the same window once again except after closure the open window.

**Finally, the code:**

```
void Widget::on_search_btn_clicked(){
    searchItem *searchBox = new searchItem;
    searchBox->setModal(false);  // <--- I want this as it is
    searchBox->show();
    searchBox->activateWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to :

1. Add `searchItem *searchBox` as member of your class.

   ```
   private:
       searchItem* m_searchBox;
   ```
2. Initialize with `new searchItem()` in the constructor.

   ```
   Widget::Widget() {
       ...
       m_searchBox = new searchItem();
   }
   ```
3. Call `void Widget::on_search_btn_clicked()` and use functions on `m_searchBox` *(consequently this is the only window that will be opened, even if it's already opened)*

   ```
   void Widget::on_search_btn_clicked(){
       m_searchBox->setModal(false);
       m_searchBox->show();
       m_searchBox->activateWindow();
   }
   ```
4. Delete in destructor

   ```
   Widget::~Widget() {
       ...
       delete m_searchBox;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

- Store searchitem on the class and create once, or
- disable button after opening, enabling when closing, or
- make dialog modal